# How to config FOSRestBundle on Symfony (step by step)

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I've seeing the docs about FOSRestBundle, but it is really confusing, And I've tried, but getting so much errors, I don't know what happend.

If you could give me a docs useful and update about it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tjamps/11d617a4b318d65ca583 maybe try and follow this one

Comment: what was the error

Comment: I'm following this tutorial https://victorroblesweb.es/2016/07/19/instalar-configurar-fosrestbundle-symfony3/ , and I getting this error `config/routing.yml" contains unsupported keys for "fos_rest": "routing_loader", "body_converter", "body_listener", "format_listener", "serializer", "view", "param_fetcher_listener". Expected one of: "resource", "type", "prefix", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition" in /app/config/routing.yml (which is being imported from "/app/config/routing_dev.yml").`

Comment: I suspect you have not yet added FOSRestBundle in AppKernel.